# Dominated splitting in dynamical system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-dynamics, celestial-mechanics

I am studying paper '' A (SHORT) SURVEY ON DOMINATED SPLITTING '' by MART´IN SAMBARINO
It is mentiend that on page 2 '' Nevertheless, since the action of Df
on the invariant subbundles might not have a unform behavior we can not get information on
how the dynamics on these “direction” would be. And so, trying to get dynamical information
from the dominated splitting seems hopeless. ''  It seems to me we can not get any useful information when the invariant set has the dominated splitting. Just we know it is robust.
Any comments to get more information are welcome.
Many thanks

Comment: You need to be more detailed. For example, what do you mean by "more information".

Comment: I would like to know if we have an invariant set that has dominated splitting. What are the theorems that give us about the dynamics of such systems? In fact, I would like to know some theorems on continuous systems with dominated invariant sets.